# Installing Sql Server 2005 SP2 - Getting error on analysis services component

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, update

At first many of the components didn't install and I followed [this workaround](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925976) (fixing user/SID mappings in registry.)

After that everything installed successfully except for analysis services.  I am getting the exact same error message as before on analysis services.  (Are there other users installed by sql server I'm not aware of perhaps?)

Do you guys have any ideas?  All of my searches seem to just point to that workaround above that I already did.

Error message from log:

```
Product                   : Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)
Product Version (Previous): 1399
Product Version (Final)   : 
Status                    : Failure
Log File                  : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Hotfix\OLAP9_Hotfix_KB921896_sqlrun_as.msp.log
Error Number              : 29528
Error Description         : MSP Error: 29528  The setup has encountered an unexpected error while Setting Internal Properties. The error is: Fatal error during installation.
```